# Unity 3d: Error UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe when buil ios

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying make my unity 3d game to build for iOS. I set the scripting backend to IL2CPP (armv7 and arm64) and i am getting the following errors..

> Failed running
>   /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Tools/UnusedByteCodeStripper2/UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe
>   -out "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed"
>   -l none -c link -x "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Tools/UnusedByteCodeStripper/native_link.xml"
>   -f "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/il2cpp/LinkerDescriptors"
>   -x "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/../platform_native_link.xml"
>   -x "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/methods_pointedto_by_uievents.xml"
>   -d "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed"
>   -a  "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll"
>   -a  "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll"
>   -a  "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll"
>   -a  "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/LitJson.dll"
>   -a  "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/System.Configuration.dll"
>   -a  "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/System.Data.dll"
>   -a  "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
>   -a  "/Users/macbook/Documents/imbatouch/project/ACT/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/System.Security.dll"
>
> stdout; ERROR: Failed to resolve base type
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationException for type
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException Fatal error in Mono
>   CIL Linker System.Exception: ERROR: Failed to resolve base type
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationException for type
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException   at
>   UnusedBytecodeStripper2.ResolveFromMonoBehaviours.IsMonoBehaviourOrScriptableObject
>   (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator35`1[Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition].MoveNext
>   () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   UnusedBytecodeStripper2.ResolveFromMonoBehaviours.Process
>   (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
>
>   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context)
>   [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run ()
>   [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at Mono.Linker.Driver.RunDriver
>   (Mono.Linker.Driver driver) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  stderr:
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String,
>   CompilerOutputParserBase)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:RunAssemblyLinker(IEnumerable`1,
>   String&, String&, String, String)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:StripAssembliesTo(String, String,
>   String&, String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:Strip(String, String, String&,
>   String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:Strip(String[], String[], String,
>   String, String&, String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunAssemblyStripper(IEnumerable,
>   String, String[], String[], String)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:StripAssemblies(IEnumerable`1,
>   String) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run()
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String,
>   IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry)
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

Answer (score 2):

This error usually indicates a problem with the .NET profile (called "Api Compatibility Level" in the Unity Editor Player Settings) you are using to build the project. I suspect that there is an assembly in the project built using a different profile than the one used to build the project. Try to change the "Api Compatibility Level" setting - that may correct this issue.